# Cucumber searches for .properties file in eclipse folder not in current project folder

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber-jvm

I am able to read a file using its absolute path, but would like to use a relative path.

Cucumber is trying to search my resource files in Eclipse directory, not in project directory.

example:

```
File f = new File("./src/values.properties");

input = new FileInputStream(f);
```

`values.properties` file is being searched in eclipse folder, not the in project folder.

Is there a way we can configure resource lookup path in `cucumber-java`?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Eclipse issue, rather than a cucumber-jvm one.

When running your test in your IDE, you can specify the execution directory.  In Eclipse Luna, this can be done by going to the *Run Configurations...* menu, and for your cucumber test, go into the *Arguments* tab, and set the *Working directory* by select “Other:” and typing in the directory in which you want to run the test.

Alternatively, you can add the property file to your classpath in the IDE, and load it using:

```
input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("values.properties");
```

Comment: Hi callonnec , thanks for your response , I am trying to run with help of cucumber plugin  for that run configuration don't have Arguments tab, I do have only following tabs-"cucumber feature runer","JRE", "Classpath" "Common". and we are doing it for multiple files. so adding specific file to class path will not work for us.